# Get Instagram Feeds using username/user id

Tags: php, codeigniter, instagram, instagram-api

Earlier I had used

[https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&variables=$result](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&variables=)

Now from this month as instagram has changed there api I am unable to get feeds.
Any suggestion will be helpfull

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? We are having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Follow my steps

first, you will need to register your application on the Instagram developer site and obtain your `Client ID` & `Client Secret` code, then you have to create `access_token` with `Client ID` & `Client Secret`

visit here : https://elfsight.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-get-instagram-access-token/ for creating `Client ID`, `Client Secret` & `access_token`

Then, add following code in your controller function

```
$access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // your access_token will be this format
$count_feed = 2; // how many feed want to load

$requestURL = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token='.$access_token.'&count='.$count_feed;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(        
    CURLOPT_URL => $requestURL,
    CURLOPT_HEADER  => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$insta_feeds = json_decode($json_response, true);

_e($insta_feeds); // $insta_feeds['data'] will return feed
```

You can get the feed by using the **Instagram library**. check out the library here : https://github.com/suhindra/CodeIgniter-Instagram-API